# CMD/Batch show variable from .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Trying to import a list of pre-set variables and show them on the screen

```
@ECHO OFF 
cls 
FOR /F %%i IN (' type list.txt ') DO (
echo %%i
)
```

But this just shows what's on the list and doing something like..
set var=%%i
echo %var%
won't do the job. 
So how should I go by to doing it?

list.txt:

```
SystemRoot
ALLUSERSPROFILE
APPDATA
CommonProgramFiles
COMPUTERNAME
ComSpec
```

Comment: No need to use the TYPE command. Remove the single quotes and just use the file name for the IN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F %%i IN (' type list.txt ') DO (
 echo %%i
 CALL ECHO %%i=%%%%i%%
)
```

When `echo` is `called`, it is executed as echo %*thecontentsof*`%%i`%

so displays the contents of required variable.

See endless articles about `delayed expansion` if you actually want to do something useful.